# Django internationalization for static website

Tags: python, django, internationalization, static-site

I'm trying to make a double-languages (italian and english) site with Django and Python.
I have followed [this](http://www.lexev.org/en/2013/multilanguage-site-django-without-redirects/) little tutorial and I'm stuck in a doubt.
I don't want any database (neither admin page) for this site, so I have deleted the database setup part in *settings.py*, then I activated "USE_I18N = True" and *ugettext* and everything else. In fact, when I go to *localhost* it shows correctly both languages translations with the */it/* and */en/* put after the *localhost:8000*.
I'm trying, now, to make a button for switching languages, adding the *[djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view)* code to my template file, here:

```
{% load i18n %}
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
<select name="language">
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
<option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
    {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

The problem is that when I choose a language from the drop-down-menu, an error shows up

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /it/i18n/setlang/
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/it/i18n/setlang/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Here's the app tree:

```
sito_personale --- locale --- en --- LC_MESSAGES --- django.mo
                                                 --- django.po
                          --- it --- LC_MESSAGES --- django.mo
                                                 --- django.po
               --- pages --- migration
                         --- static
                         --- templates
               --- sito_personale
               --- manage.py
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Could you supply your settings? I guess it has to do with how the language preference is stored ^^

Comment: Do you mean the whole settings.py code? If that's it, here you are: http://codepad.org/7xUdEGKv

I think there could be some sort of error in urls.py too: http://codepad.org/pkUn1xI4

Answer (score 1):

Django saves the selected language to the session. [`SESSION_ENGINE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#session-engine) defaults to use the database and since you don't use the `db` this might result in the exception you are getting.

Try to set `SESSION_ENGINE` to `django.contrib.sessions.backends.file`, which instead will store session data on disk (see [Using file-based sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#using-file-based-sessions)).

So in your **settings.py** add:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'
```

---

**Update**

If your site doesn't need support for sessions you could also remove the session middleware. In that case Django will use cookies to store the language preference

> The view expects to be called via the POST method, with a language
>   parameter set in request. If session support is enabled, the view
>   saves the language choice in the user’s session. Otherwise, it saves
>   the language choice in a cookie that is by default named
>   django_language. (The name can be changed through the
>   LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME setting.)

---

**Update** Follow-up question from comment

As by the [warning in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view), the `i18n` pattern needs to be in the language independent urlpatterns:

> **Warning**
>   Make sure that you don’t include the above URL within i18n_patterns()
>   - it needs to be language-independent itself to work correctly.

Here is a quick example of how that might translate to your **urls.py** from above:

```
urlpatterns = solid_i18n_patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'sito_personale.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'', include('pages.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)
```

Comment: Ok, there are some progresses: now I don't get the dabatase error anymore, but when I click to change the language (i.e. The default language is "italian" and I choose "english") the page loads, but the value in the form gets back to the default one.

Comment: And does also the language remain the same (Italian in that case) or does the page display the English?

Comment: I've updated the answer regarding the follow-up question. Could you try that configuration and see if this solves the problem?

Comment: The outcome is still the same: select language -> click -> re-load -> same page (either form and translation) :-(

Comment: Maybe I've done something wrong with the translation ".po" files?

Comment: Since your translations work when you open `/en/` and `/it/` I'd say your translation files are ok. One thing you could try is using Django's own `i18n_pattern` and deactivating `solid_i18n_patterns`. That way you could check if the problem is on the Django level or maybe configuration of `solid_i18n` plays a part in it. Also, in your language switcher, did you check the url that `{{ redirect_to }}` points at?

Comment: Uhm, how could I do that - the checking of the url? I'm pretty new to Django coding, so please excuse me if I'm making stupid requests! Anyway, "i18n_pattern" substituted to "solid_i18n" doesn't work either...

Comment: I've made a little step that could mean something - I don't know, maybe. I have changed LANGUAGE_CODE in settings.py from "en-us" to "it" and now, when I'm on the italian version of the page the translation-button works, but the opposite (I've got the english version and I click "italian" on the drop-down menu) still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you get any further with this? As the current issues seem to be unrelated to the initial question (the database error) maybe it would be the best idea to post a new question addressing your current problem. Otherwise this comment thread is getting too long and addresses two different problems.

Comment: I haven't come to a resolution yet. Anyway, the problem was that I couldn't get the language-switch button to work, but maybe you're right, and I should probably post another question!

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution, but I don't know if it's the correct/best one.
I have changed, in the template code:

```
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
```

to

```
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
```

and now it works flawlessly! I hope it's the best way to the solve the issue, if anyone could answer my doubt about it, I'd really appreciate that.